# Caffe OSX boost error

Tags: python, macos, boost, boost-python, caffe

I've installed all the dependencies to install caffe and followed the instructions online. I even downgraded my boost version to 1.57. However, I'm still getting boost errors that I can't seem to find an explanation for anywhere. Anyone have advice? I've tried boost 1.6 instead but I get similar smart_ptr errors like the 1.58 version causes. Errors are below

```
CXX src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cpp
In file included from src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp:9:
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/rng.hpp:7:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp:30:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/random/detail/seed_impl.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_signed.hpp:14:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:84: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:28:17: note: declared here
template <class T>
                ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:89: error: non-friend class member 'unqualified_type' cannot have a qualified name
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                      ~~^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:89: error: typedef declarator cannot be qualified
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                      ~~^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:105: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                                        ^
In file included from src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp:9:
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/rng.hpp:7:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp:30:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/random/detail/seed_impl.hpp:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_signed.hpp:15:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_enum.hpp:14:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/intrinsics.hpp:139:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_volatile.hpp:44:105: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = ::boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::is_volatile);
                                                                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/suffix.hpp:394:72: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT'
#     define BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(type, assignment) static const type assignment
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_volatile.hpp:38:17: note: declared here
template <class T>
                ^
In file included from src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp:9:
In file included from ./include/caffe/util/rng.hpp:7:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp:30:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/random/detail/seed_impl.hpp:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp:19:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp:57:105: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = ::boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::is_const);
                                                                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/suffix.hpp:394:72: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT'
#     define BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(type, assignment) static const type assignment
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp:51:17: note: declared here
template <class T>
                ^
6 errors generated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:15:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/intrinsics.hpp:139:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_volatile.hpp:44:105: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = ::boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::is_volatile);
                                                                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/suffix.hpp:394:72: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT'
#     define BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(type, assignment) static const type assignment
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_volatile.hpp:38:17: note: declared here
template <class T>
                ^
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:15:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:84: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                   ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:28:17: note: declared here
template <class T>
                ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:89: error: non-friend class member 'unqualified_type' cannot have a qualified name
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                      ~~^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:89: error: typedef declarator cannot be qualified
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                      ~~^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/remove_cv.hpp:31:105: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
   typedef typename boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::unqualified_type type;
                                                                                                        ^
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/move.hpp:27:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/move/utility.hpp:21:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/move/traits.hpp:20:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_nothrow_move_assignable.hpp:15:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/has_trivial_move_assign.hpp:16:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp:57:105: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
   BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(bool, value = ::boost::detail::cv_traits_imp<BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM(T)>::is_const);
                                                                                                        ^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/suffix.hpp:394:72: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT'
#     define BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(type, assignment) static const type assignment
                                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_const.hpp:51:17: note: declared here
template <class T>
                ^
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_calendar.hpp:13:
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:45:7: error: type 'greg_weekday_rep' (aka 'constrained_value<greg_weekday_policies>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday'
      greg_weekday_rep(day_of_week_num)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:48:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
    unsigned short as_number() const {return value_;}
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp:55:68: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
    weekday_enum as_enum() const {return static_cast<weekday_enum>(value_);}
                                                                   ^
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_calendar.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_ymd.hpp:14:
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_day.hpp:44:45: error: type 'greg_day_rep' (aka 'constrained_value<greg_day_policies>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'boost::gregorian::greg_day'
    greg_day(unsigned short day_of_month) : greg_day_rep(day_of_month) {}
                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_day.hpp:45:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
    unsigned short as_number() const {return value_;}
                                             ^
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_day.hpp:46:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
    operator unsigned short()  const {return value_;}
                                             ^
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/lock_types.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_time.hpp:11:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_system.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_config.hpp:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp:19:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_calendar.hpp:16:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_ymd.hpp:15:
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_year.hpp:41:38: error: type 'greg_year_rep' (aka 'constrained_value<greg_year_policies>') is not a direct or virtual base of 'boost::gregorian::greg_year'
    greg_year(unsigned short year) : greg_year_rep(year) {}
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_year.hpp:42:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value_'
    operator unsigned short()  const {return value_;}
                                             ^
In file included from src/caffe/common.cpp:1:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread.hpp:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/thread/thread_only.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/i                                               ^
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be that `BOOST_TT_AUX_CV_TRAITS_IMPL_PARAM` is not defined. I can reproduce your error with a [standalone C++ file that undefines that symbol](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9226caa7a64d1b8). You should first check if a file that only includes mersenne_twister.hpp compiles on your system. If it does, the problem is somewhere in your makefiles, possibly something that prevents including cv_traits_impl.hpp where the macro is defined. Providing the actual compilation commands (`make VERBOSE=1` might work) would help.

Comment: If you can inject a `-H` into your compiler flags to output all the files that the preprocessor encounters, that can help to debug errors including inconsistent files.